# Importing .py converted ipython notebook without changing pylab syntax

Tags: numpy, matplotlib, ipython, jupyter-notebook

In an Ipython notebook, I have defined a function to plot data. I would like to import the function in my current notebook to use it.
I tried to convert the mynotebook.ipynb to a mynotebook.py file and then just do

```
from mynotebook import myfunction
```

But I get an error.
The problem is that I wrote the original notebook with starting ipython with the option pylab.
That means that to make it work, instead of writing  something like

```
x = arange(1,10)
y = arange(1,10)
scatter(x, y)
```

I should change it to the more explicit:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib as plt
x = np.arange(1,10)
y = np.arange(1,10)
plt.scatter(x, y)
```

In my case my file is quite complex and changing it will be a pain...
Is there a way to import my notebook without modifying the .py file line by line???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
from matplotlib.pylab import *
```

will take care of all of your imports, but some of the interactive stuff (`show` etc) might not work correctly.